# .NET CLI installing SDK via global.json file

Tags: .net, dotnet-cli

When using the `--jsonfile` flag of the `[dotnet-install script]`[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) I am getting some unexpected behavior with the `rollForward` property set to `latestFeature`

My global.json file referenced:

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "6.0.416",
        "rollForward": "latestFeature"
    }
}
```

as of today (11/29/2023), there exists a newer version [`6.0.417`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) of the SDK which was released November 14, 2023.  My expectation based on the similar example provided in the the documentation, is that with the `rollForward` property set to `latestFeature`, I should get `6.0.417` installed in my CI environment with the above `global.json` file - however, I'm getting the exact version (`6.0.416`) that is specified in the `global.json` file.

**Documentation example indicates:**

"The following example shows how to use the latest feature band and patch version installed of a specific major and minor version. The JSON shown disallows any SDK version earlier than 3.1.102 and allows 3.1.102 or any later 3.1.xxx version, such as 3.1.103 or 3.1.200."

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.102",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```

**CI environment output:**

```
[Container] 2023/11/29 18:06:38.363022 Running command /usr/local/bin/dotnet-install.sh --jsonfile global.json
dotnet-install: Attempting to download using primary link https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.416/dotnet-sdk-6.0.416-linux-x64.tar.gz
dotnet-install: Remote file https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.416/dotnet-sdk-6.0.416-linux-x64.tar.gz size is 186347163 bytes.
dotnet-install: Extracting zip from https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.416/dotnet-sdk-6.0.416-linux-x64.tar.gz
dotnet-install: Downloaded file size is 186347163 bytes.
dotnet-install: The remote and local file sizes are equal.
dotnet-install: Installed version is 6.0.416
dotnet-install: Adding to current process PATH: `/root/.dotnet`. Note: This change will be visible only when sourcing script.
dotnet-install: Note that the script does not resolve dependencies during installation.
dotnet-install: To check the list of dependencies, go to https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install, select your operating system and check the "Dependencies" section.
dotnet-install: Installation finished successfully.

[Container] 2023/11/29 18:06:47.220747 Running command dotnet --version
6.0.416
```